# E.F. Code First Update One to Many error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a simple One to Many Mapping like this:

```
public class Parent{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Child> Childs { get; set;}
}

public class Child{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int ParentId { get; set; }

    public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

I use fluent API to mapping the relashionship:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>()
.HasKey(x => x.Id)
.HasMany(x => x.Childs)
.WithRequired().HasForeignKey<int>(x => x.ParentId).WillCascadeOnDelete();

modelBuilder.Entity<Child>().HasKey(e => e.Id);
```

So, when I'm trying to update Parent with new childs, removing, adding or deleting, I'm getting this error:

> The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

I'm also using PropertyInfo to set changed values from new 'Parent' to 'Old' before SaveChanges, like that.

```
 public T Update(T entity)
{
  using (U entityContext = new U())
  {
    T existingEntity = UpdateEntity(entityContext, entity);
    SimpleMapper.PropertyMap(entity, existingEntity);

    entityContext.SaveChanges();
    return existingEntity;
  }
}
```

What is going wrong, can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, somehow you deprive `Child`s from their `Parent`s. Hard to tell where. Your code doesn't reveal much.

Comment: I was trying to update Childs just updating Parent, to map values I use this method that has PropertyInfo loop to track new values:

    'SimpleMapper.PropertyMap(entity, existingEntity);'

Then I use this code below to update just Parent properties instead to update Childs as well. But before update Parent I manually update Childs and everything works fine.

    'entityContext.Entry(existingEntity).CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);'

Thanks!